# Right-alignment text in PDFBOX?

Tags: java, apache, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I need to draw text in right alignment using PDFBOX (java).

I am currently using ContentStream.drawString to draw text to the pdf. I'm not using monospace font, so the width of characters varies.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Easy solution!

```
text_width = (myFont.getStringWidth(myString) / 1000.0f) * fontSize;
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(-text_width, 0);
contentStream.drawString(myString);
contentStream.moveTextPositionByAmount(text_width, 0);
```

Where myFont = the font you are using, fontSize is the size of the font, and myString is the line of text you want to draw.

Comment: For simplicity sake, I assume, this code does not take horizontal scaling, character spacing, and word spacing into account.

Comment: is `number_width` == `text_width` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry that must have been a bug. Basically you get the (physical) length of the string, move the cursor that much back, print the string, move the cursor to the right side again.

Comment: Why divide by 1000?

Answer (score 4):

I based my answer from this of @mirror31

```html
    float pagewidth = page.getMediaBox().getWidth();
    float text_width = (font.getStringWidth(text) / 1000.0f) * size;
    float x = pagewidth - ((paddingRight * 2) + text_width);

    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(x, 0);
    contentStream.setFont(font, size);
    contentStream.showText(text);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(-x, 0);
```

I hope this can help someone